# PHP compare two arrays from different locations

Tags: php, arrays

I am wanting to compare two different arrays.  Basically I have a database with phrases in and on my website I have a search function where the user types in a phrase.
When they click search I have a PHP page which 'explodes' the string typed in by the user and its put into an array.
Then I pull all the phrases from my database where I have also used the 'explode' function and split all the words into an array.
I now want to compare all the arrays to find close matches with 3 or more words matching each phrase.

How do I do this?

Well what I've tried totally failed, but here is what I have

```
$search_term = filter_var($_GET["s"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //user entered data
$search_term = str_replace ("?", "", $search_term); //removes question marks

$array = explode(" ", $search_term);  //breaks apart user entered data

foreach ($array as $key=>$word) {
$array[$key] = " title LIKE '%".$word."%' ";  //creates condition for MySQL query
}

$q = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE  " . implode(' OR ', $array) . " LIMIT 0,10";
$r = mysql_query($q);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r)){
    $thetitle = $row['title'];
    $thetitle = str_replace ("?", "", $thetitle);
    $title_array[] = $thetitle;

$newarray = explode(" ", $search_term);

foreach ($newarray as $key=>$newword) {
    foreach($title_array as $key => $value) {
        $thenewarray = explode(" ", $value);
        $contacts = array_diff_key($thenewarray, array_flip($newarray));
        foreach($contacts as $key => $value) {
                echo $newword."<br />";
                echo $value."<br /><hr />";     
        }

    }

}
```

But basically all I want is to display suggested phrases which are similar to what the user has already typed into the search box.
So If I searched "How do I compare two arrays that have the same values?",  I would see 10 suggestions that are worded similar, so like "How to compare multiple arrays?" or "can I compare two arrays" etc...

So basically like when I first posted this question on this site, I got other questions that may help, thats basically what I want.  This code im using was origionally to match just one word or an exact matching string, im editing it to find matching words and only show phrases with 3 or more matching words.

Comment: Give us example data, expected output, example code of an attempted solution and what is currently not working. This is too abstract to answer in any detail.

Comment: Even if you do get this to work, it is going to be horribly inefficient with large amounts of data. You need to look at optimizing your data structure, and delegating as much work as possible to the database.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is the best solution for your search script. But I'll try to give you the answer:

```
<?php

    $string1 = "This is my first string";
    $string2 = "And here is my second string";

    $array1 = explode(" ", $string1);
    $array2 = explode(" ", $string2);

    $num = 0;
    foreach($array1 as $arr) {
        if(in_array($arr, $array2))
             $num++;
    }

    $match = $num >= 3 ? true : false;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use  array_intersect function

```
    $firstArray = "This is a test  only";
    $secondArray = "This is test";
    $array1 = explode(" ", $firstArray);
    $array2 = explode(" ", $secondArray);

    $result = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
    $noOfWordMatch = count($result);
    $check = $noOfWordMatch >= 3 ? true : false; ;
```

Comment: Thanks, I just tested this and althought its not how I want it, it does work to some extent, so im sure I might be able to tweak it for my page.  Thanks